# How can I prevent SIGWINCH ignored from occurring?

Tags: python-3.x, linux-kernel, operating-system, gunicorn

I made a flask application and published it with gunicorn3 but one of my functions is not working properly. I also call one scripted screen and SIGWINCH ignored it. Gives the error gunicorn3. I called directly to normal without starting with the screen and it worked. So it accesses the terminal. but I want to run the script behind and read its output. What can I do to make this function work properly?

```
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8949] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8949] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8949] [INFO] Listening at: unix:flaskapp.sock (8949)
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8949] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8981] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8981
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8984] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8984
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8985] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8985
[2020-07-05 11:10:51 +0200] [8949] [DEBUG] 3 workers
[2020-07-05 11:11:12 +0200] [8984] [DEBUG] GET /
[2020-07-05 11:11:12 +0200] [8981] [DEBUG] GET /favicon.ico
[2020-07-05 11:11:18 +0200] [8981] [DEBUG] GET /kontrolpaneli
[2020-07-05 11:11:18 +0200] [8981] [DEBUG] GET /login
[2020-07-05 11:11:26 +0200] [8985] [DEBUG] POST /login
[2020-07-05 11:11:26 +0200] [8981] [DEBUG] GET /
[2020-07-05 11:11:31 +0200] [8984] [DEBUG] GET /kontrolpaneli
[2020-07-05 11:11:32 +0200] [8984] [DEBUG] GET /kontrolpaneli
[2020-07-05 11:11:33 +0200] [8985] [DEBUG] GET /botbaslatma
[2020-07-05 11:11:37 +0200] [8985] [DEBUG] POST /botbaslatma
[2020-07-05 11:11:37 +0200] [9051] [DEBUG] worker: SIGWINCH ignored.  *** here ***
[2020-07-05 11:11:38 +0200] [8984] [DEBUG] GET /kontrolpaneli
[2020-07-05 13:12:46 +0200] [8984] [DEBUG] GET /robots.txt
[2020-07-05 13:12:49 +0200] [8981] [DEBUG] GET /about
```

more details
[github issue link code,service file etc.](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2372)